# Why does QGIS hang when I try to create a vector grid?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, vector-grid

I am working in OpenLayers plugin. I need to project the satellite data with respect to vector data shapefile I have. Andre Joost suggested to create vector grid with vector data reference system. But when I create the vector grid the system hangs, what is the problem?

Comment: A good question should contain all information necessary to reproduce the problem. Please include information on which settings you used, which input files you are working with, the CRS of your input data, the extent, ...

Answer (score 6):

The most popular problem with the vector grid tool is the preset of 0,0001000000 for x and y value.

If your CRS is in degrees, it will create a grid with 0.0001° spacing. That's most probably not what you want. For CRS in meters, you would get a 0.1mm spacing.

So set the value to 0.1° (or 1000 metres), and see if you like the result.

Comment: Thank you!from where i can change the value could u please help me because i am a learner in qgis?

Comment: If you click on `Vector -> Research tools -> Vector grid`, the parametres are in the middle of the form. And check `Raster as Polygons` too.

Comment: Oh Yes! I am getting a vector grid .After that what can i do?Whether i have to clip the satellite data with the grid i am having?

Comment: That should better be another question. Please mark this one as accepted.

Comment: Sorry i cant understand what u said could you please tell me clearly?

Comment: In this Question&Answer system, every topic should have only one question (here: creating vector grids). If the answer was helpful, you can click on the left side and mark the answer as accepted, which means this question is answered, and can be closed. For the clipping, please start another question.